# 502 Connection reset by peer when apply discount code - Magento 2

Tags: magento, nginx, magento2

I am facing the 502 related error by applying the coupon code when we are on checkout page payment step and getting below error with browser console.

**Error :** NetworkError: 502 Connection reset by peer - {site_url}/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/2439a83d3603facae410aeec2b122b1a/coupons/aaa

I've applied some solutions for the nginx server as below but not resolved my issue.

Changed some nginx server configuration with fields.

> fastcgi_connect_timeout, fastcgi_send_timeout, fastcgi_read_timeout

Other Magento API works perfect for overall site, Is there any server configuration issue which I am missing?

We are using Magento with nginx.

Any help would be appreciate !!!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use opcache? also you could try to check your php-fpm settings

Comment: Yes, I am using opcache... Which settings I have to check for php-fpm? I am using PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **php.ini** file or **opcache.ini** file and try increasing the caching memory like this (by default should be 64 or 128)

```
[opcache]
opcache.memory_consumption = 512
```

Try setting this in nginx.conf:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;
keepalive_requests 1024;
keepalive_timeout 10s;
```

In /etc/security/limits.conf add at the end of the file:

```
nginx       soft    nofile   10000
nginx       hard    nofile   70000
```

In /etc/sysctl.conf (save the file & run sysctl -p after that so you'll activate the changes):

```
fs.file-max = 209708
```

Try settting something like this in php-fpm.d/ for the desired pool (in my case it's /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 15
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 50
pm.process_idle_timeout = 90s
pm.max_requests = 4096
```

Restart nginx, restart php-fpm and check if you see any improvement

Comment: When I edit the nginx.conf file and restart the service it's giving me an error..So I think I am not able to edit that config file.
Also I am not able to found any php(php-fpm.d) instance inside etc folder.
Have you any idea regarding this?

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache?!

Comment: I am using nginx.

Comment: That's weird... Are you sure you have php installed and configured on that server (php, php-fpm and the default required php extensions for magento)?

Comment: Yes, my Magento site is working properly, I contacted to hosting provider.
He found the issue of the server optimization and he will be fix the issue..Thanks for your help.. +1 from my end.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could provide a little help